# Custom Photo Pinpoints on the Google Maps

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

How can I add styled round photo pinpoints similar to the pinpoints shown in the screenshot?
I'm building something like this now, but I don't like the number of "hacks" to achieve this.

Open source library or code sample will be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With v2 of the map library your possibilities are limited, since the custom drawing code basically has to be executed before you add markers to the map, even if those are not yet visible, while the previous overlay model allowed for a delayed drawing when a certain pin came into view. So in general you have to be very careful about memory, i.e. cache drawn bitmaps, and you have to look out / test for [leaks in the v2 maps library](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4703) when adding / clearing many custom markers.

The actual way I went down to create custom markers was the following:

1. create a custom drawable that encapsulates the drawing code for each of your markers in its `void draw(Canvas)` method
2. draw each marker drawable to a bitmap by creating a new bitmap using the calculated width / height of the drawable, attaching the bitmap to a `Canvas` and calling the draw method of the drawable with that canvas
3. create a bitmap descriptor via GMap's `BitmapDescriptor.fromBitmap(bitmap);`
4. add the bitmap to the `MarkerOptions` of the marker

Hope that helps.